# How to CREATE TABLE USING delta with Spark 2.4.4?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

This is Spark 2.4.4 and Delta Lake 0.5.0.

I'm trying to create a table using delta data source and seems I'm missing something. Although the `CREATE TABLE USING delta` command worked fine neither the table directory is created nor `insertInto` works.

The following `CREATE TABLE USING delta` worked fine, but `insertInto` failed.

```
scala> sql("""
create table t5
USING delta
LOCATION '/tmp/delta'
""").show

scala> spark.catalog.listTables.where('name === "t5").show
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|name|database|description|tableType|isTemporary|
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|  t5| default|       null| EXTERNAL|      false|
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+

scala> spark.range(5).write.option("mergeSchema", true).insertInto("t5")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: `default`.`t5` requires that the data to be inserted have the same number of columns as the target table: target table has 0 column(s) but the inserted data has 1 column(s), including 0 partition column(s) having constant value(s).;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PreprocessTableInsertion.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$PreprocessTableInsertion$$preprocess(rules.scala:341)
  ...
```

I thought I'd create with columns defined, but that didn't work either.

```
scala> sql("""
create table t6
(id LONG, name STRING)
USING delta
LOCATION '/tmp/delta'
""").show
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: delta does not allow user-specified schemas.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:325)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$logicalPlan$1(Dataset.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:3370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
  ... 54 elided
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** `CREATE TABLE USING delta` is not supported by Spark before 3.0.0 and Delta Lake before 0.7.0.

---

Delta Lake 0.7.0 with Spark 3.0.0 (both just released) do support `CREATE TABLE` SQL command.

Be sure to "install" Delta SQL using `spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog` configuration property with `org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog`.

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit \
  --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0 \
  --conf spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension \
  --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog

scala> spark.version
res0: String = 3.0.0

scala> sql("CREATE TABLE delta_101 (id LONG) USING delta").show
++
||
++
++

scala> spark.table("delta_101").show
+---+
| id|
+---+
+---+

scala> sql("DESCRIBE EXTENDED delta_101").show(truncate = false)
+----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|col_name                    |data_type                                                |comment|
+----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|id                          |bigint                                                   |       |
|                            |                                                         |       |
|# Partitioning              |                                                         |       |
|Not partitioned             |                                                         |       |
|                            |                                                         |       |
|# Detailed Table Information|                                                         |       |
|Name                        |default.delta_101                                        |       |
|Location                    |file:/Users/jacek/dev/oss/spark/spark-warehouse/delta_101|       |
|Provider                    |delta                                                    |       |
|Table Properties            |[]                                                       |       |
+----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: applying mentioned spark configurations fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

The OSS version of Delta does not have the SQL Create Table syntax as of yet. This will be implemented the future versions using Spark 3.0.

To create a Delta table, you must write out a DataFrame in Delta format. An example in Python being

```
df.write.format("delta").save("/some/data/path")
```

Here's a [link](https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#create-a-table) to the create table documentation for Python, Scala, and Java.

Answer (score 7):

An example with pyspark 3.0.0 & delta 0.7.0

```
print(f"LOCATION '{location}")
spark.sql(f"""
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE  {TABLE_NAME} (
  CD_DEVICE INT, 
  FC_LOCAL_TIME TIMESTAMP,  
  CD_TYPE_DEVICE STRING,
  CONSUMTION DOUBLE,
  YEAR INT,
  MONTH INT, 
  DAY INT )
USING DELTA
PARTITIONED BY (YEAR , MONTH , DAY, FC_LOCAL_TIME)
LOCATION '{location}'
""")
```

Where "location" is a dir HDFS for spark cluster mode save de delta table.